# Why am i getting null and zeros in pivot field values column in tableau?

Tags: pivot, pivot-table, tableau-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxPg5.png)Hi,

When i try to convert my data source( that contains a list of countries as columns with daily deaths noted)into pivot(converting the list of country columns into a single column with all the countries as rows) in tableau, I am getting null values for the column pivot field values.

Here i am attaching my original data source and the sheet which is pivoted

Comment: No data/sheet is uploaded, as stated.

Answer (score 0):

The pivot values show null because there are no data available. Note that, the Tableau data pane will only show you a sample of your data. when you go into Tableau sheet to create your views you can drag pivot value into text in the marks card. That is a true test to see if there are numbers in the pivot value field.